# Create Pandas Dataframe from specified columns' names in Excel like pd.read_csv or pd.read_excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, xlwings

With pd.read_csv or pd.read_excel, I can easily create a Dataframe from specified columns of csv or Excel file.

But in some cases, I can only use excel file and pd.read_excel works too slow and I hear that we can use Xlwings to speed up.

I have tried to search many times but I cannot find how to create Pandas Dataframe from specified columns' names in Excel ( my file has hundreds columns and I just need to use some ).
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just `Save as csv` in Excel, then use `read_csv`?

Comment: Our language is not English, saving as csv makes font errors and my users dont know and dont want to do.

Answer (score 1):

**pandas:**

you can use the following code to read specified columns names & values:

```
 pd.read_excel('path\\filename.xlsx', sheet_name='products', usecols="B:E")
```

to know more about 'usecols' refer [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

**Xlwings:**

To install xlwings via pip or conda, refer this [documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html#installation).

you can use the following code to read specified columns names & values:

```
import xlwings as xw 
wb = xw.Book(r'path\\filename.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['products'] #add your sheetname of your excel file.
sht.range('B1:E1').value #read specified columns names
output: [' date     ', 'item_id', 'revenue', 'revenue1', 'revenue2']
sht.range('B1:E1').expand().value #read specified columns names & values.
output: [['item_id', 'revenue', 'revenue1', 'revenue2'], [59.0, 22131846.0, 1212.0, 3223.0], [60.0, 22131847.0, 1213.0, 3224.0]]
```

example excelsheet:
[image: output]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank @Jose Praveen, I know how to use USECOLS, but I cannot mimic it with xlwings. I have searched xlwings doc, it seems that I have to specify Range, not Column name